# How to customize the appearance of ASP.Net Login control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to style **ASP.Net Login** control.

```
<asp:Login ID="login" runat="server" DisplayRememberMe="false" 
   onloggedin="LogIn_LoggedIn">
</asp:Login>
```

I would like to expand it to view all the table cells and such.

Comment: This is very broad .... and also subjective "I want it to look better" can you be more specific about what you want your login page to look like?

Comment: I'm sorry. I dont have anything specific in mind. With "styling" i mean, styling textboxes, button and so on!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In designer view, you can convert the **Login** control to **Template**.

[image]

It'll create the following code for you. ***Note:*** Make sure you do not rename controls' ID.

```
<asp:Login ID="login" runat="server" DisplayRememberMe="false"
    OnLoggedIn="LogIn_LoggedIn">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2">Log In</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="login">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="login">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="login" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Comment: Thank you. So dumb and easy haha!